# Query From Shared Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a shared Data Extensions across multiple Business Units.

I need to run a query from it in a Child BU but every time I try to run I get

> "× An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Leads is
>   not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query
>   existing data extensions or system data views."

Is there a special prefix I need to add in the FROM portion of the Query?

Query is:

```
SELECT...
FROM Leads
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. To query any shared Data Extensions from a child you need to add the `Ent.` prefix to it.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM ent.Leads
```